# Nonstandard type declaration in Fortran 2003

Tags: fortran, standards, variable-declaration, fortran2003

I've written a scientific fortran code without using any specific fortran standard. But I have now to declare which fortran standard I'm using.

I said I'm using fortran 2003 because I need the get_command_argument and command_argument_count intrinsic functions. However when using the flag -std=f2003 to check the code standards the compilation fails.

I get errors concerning the type declaration of reals in some parts. For example when I declare variables in the module:

```
module innout
implicit none
real*8,parameter               :: nan=-1.
real*8,allocatable,save        :: windU(:),windV(:)
real*8,allocatable,save        :: input_param(:,:),input_rad(:,:)
real*8,allocatable,save        :: prein(:),input(:),ref_lev(:)
character(30),allocatable,save :: sceneclass(:)
end module innout
```

I get the messages "Nonstandard type declaration REAL*8" in all real variables.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: Try to use `real64` instead.

Comment: Thanks but I think that's for Fortran 2008

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kind` specifier is the way to go...

If you limit yourself to Fortran 2003 Standard, then you need to use the `kind()` or `selected_real_kind()` function to determine the corresponding kind first:

```
module innout
  implicit none
  integer,parameter                  :: REAL64 = kind(1.d0)

  real(kind=REAL64),parameter        :: nan=-1._REAL64
  real(kind=REAL64),allocatable,save :: windU(:),windV(:)
  real(kind=REAL64),allocatable,save :: input_param(:,:),input_rad(:,:)
  real(kind=REAL64),allocatable,save :: prein(:),input(:),ref_lev(:)
  character(30),allocatable,save     :: sceneclass(:)
end module innout
```

If you are allowed to/your compiler supports Fortran 2008, I would recommend the module `ISO_Fortran_env` and the pre-defined constant `REAL64`:

```
module innout
  use,intrinsic :: ISO_Fortran_env, only: REAL64
  implicit none
  real(kind=REAL64),parameter         :: nan=-1._REAL64
  real(kind=REAL64),allocatable,save  :: windU(:),windV(:)
  real(kind=REAL64),allocatable,save  :: input_param(:,:),input_rad(:,:)
  real(kind=REAL64),allocatable,save  :: prein(:),input(:),ref_lev(:)
  character(30),allocatable,save      :: sceneclass(:)
end module innout
```

Comment: Or, just to be awkward, `integer, parameter :: real64 = kind(1.d0)` and moving to the 2008 standard will be so much easier :-)

Comment: I've checked and I can also use the 2008 standard, so I will then use that option. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

`real*8` is not, and never has been, a Fortran-standard type declaration.  These days the simplest approach to declaring a 64-bit real is probably to import the *named-constant* `real64` from the intrinsic module `iso_fortan_env`, like this:

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
...
real(real64) :: my_var
```

There are other ways, involving `selected_real_kind` and other mechanisms, but if you want to program with IEEE floating-point types then `real64` and `real32` are a good way to go.

As @AlexanderVogt has pointed out in a comment these standard named constants were added to the language in the 2008 standard.  Most recent compiler versions I have worked with already implement them.

Comment: `REAL64` is not available for `ISO_Fortran_env` in Fortran 2003! Named constants were added in 2008.

Comment: Well, well, well, I thought they were added in 2003.

Comment: See [*"The new features of Fortran 2008,"* Ch. 10.12, "Named Constants"](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1701-N1750/N1729.pdf) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found already the answer.

Using the following in the variable declaration, it seems to work fine:

```
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
```

From http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Real+precision